# JSF convertNumber throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch Error

Tags: java, jsf

I'm using JSF 1.2. My IDE is RAD.

In my xhtml page Iam using a convertNumber tag to format an Integer variable. Integers need to be left padded with 0's if they are not 4 digits long (If the Integer value is 21, it should be displayed as 0021)

I have used a convertNumber to acheive this.

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="0000"/>
```

It looks fine when the values are being displayed, but when i try to input an integer value into the textbox, and try to save it, it throws the following error:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is custom validators the only way to acheive this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `<f:convertNumber minIntegerDigits="4"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, Im still receiving the Illegal ArgumentException.

Comment: @Raam Is it the value in bean of Integer type? Please provide more details to the question: inputText code you use, bean code you are using.

Comment: I apologize for not following up with your post. I used Custom Validators to overcome this issue. It dies reference a bean variable of Integer type which I think was causing the exception.

Comment: Any idea of how such a converter should be like ? @Raam